# Jenkins unable to run Calabash-iOS in the simulator

Tags: ios, jenkins, cucumber, ui-automation, calabash-ios

I am trying to run some test in the emulator using Jenkins, but whenever I start Cucumber, the script stop trying to launch UIAutomation.

Here are some facts:

- I am using the last version of Cucumber, Calabash-ios and Run Loop
- Jenkins is running as local LaunchAgent (`~jenkins/Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist`)
- I already added `jenkins` user to `_developer` group, turn it in an `admin`
- I set `DevToolsSecurity -enable`
- I am not able to set `security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport is-developer` as it always return an error
- **Running the same test from the console over SSH works fine**
- **Running the same test from Jenkins on a real device, works fine**
- I am running Jenkins into a VirtualBox machine
  I have already tried to increase the timeout for Calabash (`@calabash_launcher.relaunch({timout: 120, :uia_timeout => 30}`)

I have run out of idea about what to try to fix the issue.
Any suggestion is more than welcome.

**UPDATE**
I have been able to run the simulator by removing the `SessionCreate` property from `org.jenkins-ci.plist`, but now, I have to enter my password to unlock the keychain everytime I run a test.

Comment: How did you remove SessionCreate? Where can I find this org.jenkins-ci.plist?

Comment: depends on your setup. I was using this guide http://www.egeek.me/2015/02/14/jenkins-in-osx-guest-in-virtualbox-for-ios-jobs-full-setup-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. To solve this I only need to export language:

`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`